Is it possible to use k6chaijs with async function? For example in k6 browser tests?
I'd like to use k6chaijs with k6 browser module, but I have observed that messages are printed in wrong order.
export default () => {
    describe('New page verifier', async () => {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        try {
            expect(page, "page").to.be.null;
        } finally {
            await page.close();
        }
    })
}

Prints output like this:
     ✗ expected page to be null
      ↳  0% — ✓ 0 / ✗ 1

     █ New page verifier

   ✗ checks...............: 0.00% ✓ 0        ✗ 1  
     data_received........: 0 B   0 B/s
     data_sent............: 0 B   0 B/s

Text from describe function is after assertion what is not expected

This seems to be a shortcoming of either k6 (0.52.0) or k6chaijs (4.3.4.3) – I assume the latter does not handle async functions correctly (or at all). You can reduce your example to a tiny MRE that does not require k6 browser:
import { describe, expect } from 'https://jslib.k6.io/k6chaijs/4.3.4.3/index.js';

export default () => {
    describe('Async test', async () => {
        const value = await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'delay'));
        expect(value, 'value').to.equal('delay');
    });
}

The test takes 2 seconds to execute (the Promise resolves after 2 seconds) and the output is in reverse:
     ✓ expected value to equal 'delay'

     █ Async test

A synchronous test outputs in the expected order:
export default () => {
    describe('Sync test', () => {
        const value = 'delay';
        expect(value, 'value').to.equal('delay');
    });
}

     █ Sync test

       ✓ expected value to equal 'delay'

describe executes the function passed as second argument, the same way that k6's group function does. Since this function is now async, it is not guaranteed to complete before describe returns and describe cannot correlate failing expectations with the current description.
The second best course of action is to report an issue in the k6chaijs bug tracker (and I see you or somebody else already has). The best course of action is to submit a pull request which fixes this issue.
